# Accessing parameters passed to $.get into success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access parameters passed as a data to $.get in 
jQuery. The code is something like this:

```
$.get(requestUrl,
         {lesson: eventParams.lessonId,
          page: eventParams.page}, 
          function(data) {
                // here I want to access 
                // lesson or page 
          });
```

Now I made something like this:

```
$.get(requestUrl,
         {lesson: eventParams.lessonId,
          page: eventParams.page}, 
          (function(contextObject) {
                return function(data) {
                // Here I accessing  
                // contextObject.lesson
                // and 
                // contextObject.page               
           }})({lesson: eventParams.lessonId,
                               page: eventParams.page});
```

This working but will be good if a can avoid using of closure. 
I would appreciate any help. 
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params object (or at least its properties) is accessible as the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of your callback, see the docs for the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`)

So use

```
$.get(requestUrl, {
    lesson: eventParams.lessonId,
    page: eventParams.page
}, function(data) {
    console.log(this);
    // use this.data.lesson or .page
});
```

---

Btw, the closure you're currently using is quite unhelpful because you have too repeat everything. It would've been easier if you just accessed `eventParams` from the callback. If you don't trust the `context` or want to use a closure for clearness, here's how to do it properly (assuming you cannot use `eventParams` because they're volatile):

```
(function() {
    var data = {
        lesson: eventParams.lessonId,
        page: eventParams.page
    };
    return $.get(requestUrl, data, function(resultData) {
        // here use data.lesson or .page 
    });
})()
```

Comment: In my case console.log(this.data) is undefined; I use jQuery v1.10.1. Your second example look great anyway! I was thing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare eventParams ?

```
var eventParams = '';
```

You can use var at global scope (outside of all functions) to declare a global variable:

```
var yourGlobalVariable;
function boo() {
    // ...
}
```

Alternately, you can assign to a property on window:

```
function foo() {
    window.yourGlobalVariable = ...;
}
```

Comment: I know these ways, but that they want to avoid. There must be some mechanism in jQuery to receive the given parameters, but apparently not.

Comment: jQuery is not the answer to everything. Why want you avoid?

Comment: Because it is good practice to avoid using global variables when it can not be used. I already use a closure, but is interesting if this can be done without it. Depends on your point of view. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @George: But you're using the closure wrong, so that you have to repeat your whole object.